# No Custom Horizontal Resolution Below 800?

Tags: pi-3b+, hdmi, display

On my RPI 3 I can edit `/boot/config.txt` and use this to get my desired resolution of 400x200.

`hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=400 200 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1`

However on my 3B+ it results in a resolution on 1600x200.

After some experimentation I found that any horizontal resolution setting of 807 or below results in an actual horizontal resolution of 1600. However, the vertical resolution setting always works.

How can I get the horizontal resolution down to 400?

Comment: Have you followed the check instructions starting at **Which values are valid for my monitor?** on https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md If so, can you post the results here by editing your question please?  You may need to put the results on pastebin if you get lots out :-)

Comment: It is actually an LED screen with a native res of 64x32. So, there won’t be any results as no actual monitor is plugged in. (Yes hotplug is turned on.)

Comment: Just for kicks I ran those commands anyways
`$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 2 modes:
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
           mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive 
$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
Group DMT has 2 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive 
  (prefer) mode 87: 808x400 @ 60Hz 15:9, clock:25MHz progressive 
$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
state 0x6 [DVI DMT (87) RGB full 15:9], 808x400 @ 60.00Hz, progressive`

Comment: Part 2
`$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d edid.dat; /opt/vc/bin/edidparser edid.dat
Nothing written!
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Failed to open edid.dat
/opt/vc/bin/edidparser exited with code -1`